# iPhone / iPad Store ID Territories - Facebook

Tags: ios, facebook, app-store-connect, ads

We've been having a few issues related to the iOS Store ID fields provided in the Facebook settings. We'd like to start promoting an app we have recently soft-launched, however we cannot apply the "Apple ID" from our iTunes Connect page to Facebook's iPhone / iPad Store ID.

We receive the error "We were unable to retrieve your iPhone Store ID from the iTunes App Store. Please double-check your ID and try again later.".

We have only soft-launched in one territory so far- South Africa. Could this possibly be the cause? If so, what are the territories will Facebook accept?

I've checked, double-checked, and triple-checked we're using the correct ID- and when using the ID from other released apps, Facebook will accept these with no quarrel (including one app released only in Canada).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes that could be the problem. Please file a bug report at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs and say that your app is only available in South Africa and it doesn't work. It is just a config change we need to do

Comment: Thank you for your swift response! I have filed a bug report as requested- https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1450092471927714/

Comment: I just fixed it for you. Should work in 15 minutes or less

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook-related issue. Now resolved!

Comment: can you tell how did you solve your problem, please?

Comment: Open an issue at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs - they will get onto it for you.